# <STDIN> not working during while - Perl

Tags: perl, while-loop, stdin

I wrote a small script, attempting to write a calculator, just to test what I know, but I have a problem, where I want to read `<STDIN>` in a while loop, and it just freezes till I kill it with `CTRL + C`.

The weird thing, is that it works in the eclipse console, but nowhere else.

Relevant code:

```
require Term::Screen::Uni;
use strict;

...

sub basicCalc(){
    my $scr = new Term::Screen::Uni;
    $scr->clrscr(); 
    print("Basic calculator - type help for information about your options!\r\n");

    while($input == "1\n"){
        bcOPR();
    }

    $scr->clrscr(); 
    main();
}

sub bcOPR(){
    my $inp = <>;
    if($inp eq "help\n"){ $input = 0; }
}
```

Comment: From the documentation of [Term::Screen](http://p3rl.org/Term::Screen), it seems you should use `getch` instead of `readline`.

Comment: In `bcOPR`, don't you need to assign `$input = $inp;` in an `else`? Also, you're using `==` where you should be using `eq`.

Comment: @RobEarl `$input` and `$inp` don't really have to do with eachother, and you are right, i do need to use eq there, thanks

Comment: @choroba At your comment, I tried removing Term::Screen and it's working properly now, though I don't really understand what happened there. Thank you!

Comment: @WolfyD: Term::Screen intercepts keyboard events, so nothing gets to the standard input.

Comment: @choroba I see, but if I need not just one char, but a string as input, what should I do? Should I just not use Term::Screen?